# Invalid image URL or error downloading from target server

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

When I am calling postAsync with particular image url, I am seeing the below error in json response.

"Invalid image URL or error downloading from target server. Remote server error returned: "An error occurred while sending the request.""

Below is the Image Url : 
http://localhost:3942/WebImages/201658211024test.jpg

Below is the code :

```
var uri = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect?" + queryString;
string jsonbody = "{\"url\":\"" + imageUrl + "\"}"; 
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonbody);
var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData);
content.Headers.ContentType = 
new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); 
response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content); 
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Can you please let me know what is the issue?
Is it because the image url has the format type at the end ? If so, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

When you make a request to the Cognitive Service API with an image URL as you've specified, you're instructing the service running in the cloud to load the image from *that* location.  The service cannot locate *your* localhost, hence the error.

You have two options: (a) if your image is already available at a *public-reachable* URL, use the URL instead.  If you're unsure whether the URL is publicly reachable, try entering it in a browser on your phone, for example. Alternatively, (b) Upload the image in the HTTP request body.  You'll need to also set the MediaTypeHeaderValue to `application/octet-stream`.

If you're using a managed language (like C#) with Visual Studio, consider using the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face) package.  This will take care of the details for you.  The source for that NuGet package is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Windows/tree/master/ClientLibrary).